# Función para recorrer archivo eliminando vocales

Tags: php

Estoy probando a leer y recorrer ficheros. No sé muy bien como crear una función que me lea un archivo de texto y me elimine las vocales existentes.
Hasta ahora tengo un código que me abre un archivo, me lo lee y me cuenta las palabras que hay en su interior. Necesito que me elimine las vocales. El código hasta ahora.

```
<?php
$fp = fopen("archivo.txt", "r");
while (!feof($fp)){
    $linea = fgets($fp);
    echo $linea;
}

echo 'PALABRAS' . 
    "\n";

echo '<br>';
 echo str_word_count(file_get_contents("archivo.txt"));

echo '<br>';

echo  ' NUEVO TEXTO' . 
    "\n";

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: revisa la documentación de str_replace, de hecho en los ejemplos viene como eliminar las vocales 
http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Pero en este caso no voy a pasarle la cadena sino que tendrá que recorrer el archivo de texto y omitir las vocales. Ahí esta el problema.

Answer (score -1):

He añadido las vocales mayúsculas, por si quieres también.

```
function eliminarVocales($frase) {
  $vocales = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U");
  return str_replace($vocales, "", $frase);
}
```

Tu archivo quedaría así:

```
    <?php
$fp = fopen("archivo.txt", "r");
while (!feof($fp)){
    $linea = fgets($fp);
    echo eliminarVocales($linea);
}

echo 'PALABRAS' .
    "\n";

echo '<br>';
 echo str_word_count(file_get_contents("archivo.txt"));

echo '<br>';

echo  ' NUEVO TEXTO' .
    "\n";

fclose($fp);

function eliminarVocales($frase) {
  $vocales = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U");
  return str_replace($vocales, "", $frase);
}
?>
```

Comment: No entiendo el voto negativo, si es lo que necesitas como dijiste en tu anterior comentario "Tendrá que recorrer el archivo de texto y omitir las vocales". ¿Lo probaste? ¿Por qué no es lo que buscas? ¿Por qué votas negativo? Podrías comentarme antes de votar negativo.

Comment: no funciona y altera el código anterior.

Comment: Ya está exactamente como lo tenías tu más la parte que hace la funcionalidad. "No funciona" no es una respuesta. Leete https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answering. Si no especificas, no te podré ayudar. ¿Qué no te funciona? ¿El código en sí? ¿El servidor? ¿Que error te sale?, Yo lo he probado en mi servidor y va bien. ¿Puedes añadir tu archivo.txt para verificar?